# Printing a CSV file

Tags: swift, csv, airprint

I'm trying to print a CSV file generated from a `Struct` Here's my best effort:

```
 @IBAction func printButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

            let fileName = "HostList.csv"
                 let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
                 var csvText = "Name,Phonenumber,E-mail\n"

                 for host in hosts {
                     let newLine = "\(host.hostName ?? ""),\("\(host.hostCountryCode ?? "")   \(host.hostPhoneNumber ?? "")"),\(host.hostEmail ?? "")\n"
                     csvText.append(contentsOf: newLine)
                 }

        do {

         try csvText.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

       let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
       let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
           printInfo.outputType = .general
           printInfo.jobName = "print Job"
           printController.printInfo = printInfo

           // 3
         let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: csvText)
           formatter.perPageContentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 72, left: 72, bottom: 72, right: 72)
           printController.printFormatter = formatter


           // 4
          printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
        }
        catch {
                      print("Failed to create file")
                      print("\(error)")
                  }
    }
```

This prints all content on one line. I want it to be separated in columns and rows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650283/printing-a-uitextview-with-a-bluetooth-printer-does-not-preserve-line-breaks ? in the doc: "To use this print formatter for a print job, create an instance of UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter initialized with the HTML, set the inherited layout properties, and add the object to the print job in one of two ways:" HTML doesn't consider \n as a new line, no? It uses `<br>` instead. Maybe with `UISimpleTextPrintFormatter` directly then?